# image_dataset_from_directory label list appear to be assigned in a random order

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I try to do the following:

1. I have 2 folders on Google Colab. First one contains PNG images and the second one contains CSV describing each image. The coresponding CSV files gave identical name to PNGs they describe, the only difference being the extension.

EXAMPLE
PNG files:
dog_1.png, dog_2.png, dog_3.png

Their CSV files are: dog_1.csv, dog_2.csv, dog_3.csv.

Content of each files is:
breed, color, weight
7, 22, 15

I select one of the feature from csv with my function get_class_label(SELECTED_FEATURE, label_file) and I split my data into classes based on that particular data:

EXAMPLE
SELECTED_FEATURE='breed'
So for the example image which csv I presented above the class label is gonna be '7'.
The labels are based on the value for selected feature for each image.

2. I go over all the PNG files. For each of them, I get the label from matching CSV and I build a label list.
3. The documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image_dataset_from_directory) states:

> Labels should be sorted according to the alphanumeric order of the
> image file paths (obtained via os.walk(directory) in Python).

so I do exactly that:

```
label_list = []
for path, directories, image_files in os.walk(images_directory):
  for image_file in image_files:
    label_file = replace_file_extension(image_file, 'png', 'csv')
    label_list.append(get_class_label(SELECTED_FEATURE, label_file))
```

4. I use image_dataset_from_directory to create Dataset from directory with custom label list:

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    images_directory,
    image_size=(32,32),
    labels=label_list,
    label_mode="int"
    )
```

I get the labels assigned to my images in what appears a random order each time I load them? What is the reason behind this problem? How can I make sure images are loaded in the correct order?

Comment: not clear on what you are doing. Can you show examples of image file list and corresponding cvs labels?

Comment: I added an example to the question for the context.

Comment: Think I understand what you are doing. see my answer below

Answer (score 2):

I found the source of the problem.

**tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory** provides images in alphanumerical order of their names.

**os.walk** does the things somehow differently (it seems to provide images ordered by last modification date), so to fix it I had to use **sorted()** on the list of files returned by os.walk.

Answer (score 0):

I created a folder C:\Temp\forder whic contains two folders. folder C:\Temp\forder\images contains 10 jpg images labelled consecutively 1.jpg, 2.jpg,....10.jpg. the folder
C:\Temp\forder\csv contains 10 csv files labelled 1.csc, 2.csc,,,,,10.csc. Each csv folder contains 3 columns 'breed', 'age', 'color' and only a single row with an integer value in each column. For the breed column the values for each csv file are consecutively numbered, so 1.csv has breed value =1, 2.csv has breed value=2 etc. Then I ran the code below which is similar to yours

```
import os
import pandas as pd
def replace_file_extension(image_file, old_ext, new_ext):
    index=image_file.rfind('.')
    ext=image_file[index + 1:]
    fname=image_file[:index]
    if ext==old_ext:
        fnew=fname + '.' + new_ext
    return fnew
def get_class_label(SELECTED_FEATURE, label_file_path):    
    df=pd.read_csv(label_file_path)    
    feature=df[SELECTED_FEATURE].iloc[0]    
    return feature

SELECTED_FEATURE='breed'
images_directory=r'c:\temp\forder\images'
label_directory=r'c:\temp\forder\csv'
label_list = []
for path, directories, image_files in os.walk(images_directory):    
    for image_file in image_files:   
        label_file = replace_file_extension(image_file, 'jpg', 'csv')
        label_file_path=os.path.join(label_directory, label_file) 
        label=get_class_label(SELECTED_FEATURE, label_file_path)
        print (image_file, '  ', label)
        label_list.append(label)
print (label_list)
```

the result were the expected list. Note that image file 10.jpg precedes 2.jpg as expected but the value of the label 10 is correct as expected printed data is shown below

```
1.jpg    1
10.jpg    10
2.jpg    2
3.jpg    3
4.jpg    4
5.jpg    5
6.jpg    6
7.jpg    7
8.jpg    8
9.jpg    9
[1, 10, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: I have very similar code, but your answer does not address my issue. My issue is that the function tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory reading files (and assigning them to my labels) in different order than os.walk.

Comment: Oh OK let me look into that